# Problem with Rake while attempting to install Diaspora on Dreamhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, dreamhost, diaspora

I am attempting to install a Diaspora pod on my Dreamhost account, following the instructions here:

https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora/wiki/Installing-and-Running-Diaspora

Everything went smooth until it was time to use Rake in order to set up the database. I created the databases using dreamhost's web interface, and then attempted the line given in the guide:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

The result being:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake: Is a directory - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake (Errno::EISDIR)
    from /usr/bin/rake:19:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/rake:19
```

It looks like some sort of Rake problem (and indeed, /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake **is** a directory).

I have some other homemade Ruby-on-Rails projects running on Dreamhost and have no similar problem with rake for them. Their rakefile looks a little different but I'm not sure what causes the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess, would it help to set RAILS_ENV=production on the end of the line?

Comment: Nope, playing with this line doesn't help. It's a general problem with the way rake works in this project.